# Flux.fromStream fails when split and merged

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have this sample code:

```
Flux<Integer> range = Flux.range(0, 10);
Flux<Long> longs = Flux.fromStream(new Random().longs(100, 500).boxed()); // (1)
// Flux<Long> longs = Flux.fromIterable(new Random().longs(100, 500).boxed().limit(30).collect(Collectors.toList())); // (2)

Flux<Tuple2<Integer, Long>> flux1 = Flux.zip(range, longs);

Flux<Integer> flux2 = flux1.map(e -> 2);
Flux<Integer> flux3 = flux1.map(e -> 3);

CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

Flux.merge(flux2, flux3)
   .doOnComplete(() -> countDownLatch.countDown())
   .subscribe(e -> log.info("{}", e));

countDownLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.spliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:343)
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.iterator(ReferencePipeline.java:139)
  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxStream.subscribe(FluxStream.java:57)
  at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7777)
  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxZip$ZipCoordinator.subscribe(FluxZip.java:579)
  ...
```

Commenting line (1) and uncommenting line (2) solves the issue, but in my use case `longs` is unbounded as in (1). How would I fix this?

The real use case is to do something when both `flux2` and `flux3` are done, they have side effects in `map` calls - writing to a file in this case, so I need to make sure all is written before I exit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defer`:

```
Flux<Long> longs = Flux.defer(() -> Flux.fromStream(new Random().longs(100, 500).boxed()));
```

Even though you have only one explicit `subscribe` you create more than one stream based on `longs`. A subscription is created for each.

`Flux.fromStream` can only be subscribed to once because Java streams can only be consumed once.

`defer` solves this problem by creating a new stream for each subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

`Flux` by design are reusable, however in line (2) you are using `Flux.fromStream` consuming Java Streams (which could be used only once) - that is why you get `stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

One of the solution would be to duplicate `longs` stream with the same seed for Random.

```
long seed = 1000000;

Flux<Long> longs = Flux.fromStream(new Random(seed).longs(100, 500).boxed());      
Flux<Long> longs1 = Flux.fromStream(new Random(seed).longs(100, 500).boxed()); 

Flux<Integer> flux2 = Flux.zip(range, longs).map(e -> 2);
Flux<Integer> flux3 = Flux.zip(range, longs1).map(e -> 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this with *any* stream, not specific to random values that can be pre-initialized?

Comment: Yes. Use `.publish().refCount(2)` on the original `Flux` to "reuse" it.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is late, but I have recently begun to use projectreactor, and you can solve this issue by using `.cache()` so that you can get the results from your stream without having to re-subscribe to your Flux.  I will leave this answer here for anyone else who happens to find this question, and to generate discussion if I am somehow in error, or if there might be some unintended consequences that I am not yet aware of.

```
package org.example.service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.util.function.Tuple2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class SplitMergeStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        Flux<Integer> range = Flux.range(0, 10);
//        Flux<Long> longs = Flux.fromStream(new Random().longs(30, 100, 500).boxed()).cache(); // (1)
        Flux<Long> longs = Flux.fromIterable(new Random().longs(30, 100, 500).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())).cache(); // (2)

        Flux<Tuple2<Integer, Long>> flux1 = Flux.zip(range, longs);

        Flux<String> flux2 = flux1.map(e -> 2 + " -> " + e);
        Flux<String> flux3 = flux1.map(e -> 3 + " -> " + e);

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Flux.merge(flux2, flux3)
                .doOnComplete(countDownLatch::countDown)
                .subscribe(e -> log.info("{}", e));

        countDownLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

I changed your `.map()` call so that you can see the exact items each time `flux1.map()` is called.  You can switch between the `flux.fromStream()` and `flux.fromIterable()` by switching which line is commented, and either one will work without giving you the error.

Since `.cache()` turns things hot, and the cache is unbounded, I am not sure what this means for really big streams of data.